# Find $M \in (E)$ so that the $MA + MB$ is minimum.

Tags: geometry

Let the ellipse $(E)$ and two points $A, B$ does not lie on $(E)$. Find $M \in (E)$ so that the $MA + MB$ is minimum. How to solve that?

Comment: Here is the same question for two points and a circle: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463978/minimize-the-sum-of-distances-between-two-point-and-a-circle. A similar approach should work in your case: Find the largest ellipse with foci A and B which *touches* E in a single point.

Comment: Use Fermat's principle.  Suppose both points lie inside the ellipse. Reflect one point ($A$, e.g.) relative to the ellipse so that is outside the ellipse (there maybe several possibilities to do this).  The connection of the reflected point $A'$ and $B$ and the first one meets the ellipse in an candidate $C$ for $M$.  Now choose that $C$ for which $BA'$ is minimal.

Comment: Symmetry. And again symmetry. One technique is to find a point of intersection of perpendicular from middlepoint of $AB$ (I don't know the correct term sorry, I mean bisector of segment) and the ellipse. It will be the point you look for.

Comment: Symmetry. And again symmetry. One technique is to find a point of intersection of perpendicular from middlepoint of $AB$ (I don't know the correct term sorry, I mean bisector of segment) and the ellipse. And compare its distance with the points of intersection of lines connecting center of ellipse with $A$, and than with corresponding point with $B$. Take the one for which you have the least distance. It will be the point you look for.

Comment: The first comment I wrote for circle, I'm sorry.