# How to determine the minimum value of the weighted sum of the distances from two points to a point on a circumference

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, maxima-minima

## Problem

In a two-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system,
there are two points $A(2, 0)$ and $B(2, 2)$
and a circle $c$ with radius $1$ centered at the origin $O(0, 0)$,
as shown in the figure below.
[image]

If $P$ is a point on the circle $c$,
then what is the minimum value of

$$ f = 2\sqrt{2}\lvert{PA}\rvert + \lvert{PB}\rvert? $$

## Hypothesis

From my experience,
the solutions to such problems do not seem to be available under elementary form in general,
as indicated by answers to the question [Minimize the sum of distances between two point and a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463978/620160).
However, when I studied this problem on [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/pvcvpvv2),
it seems that minimum value is exactly $5$ in this specific situation,
with $P$ located at roughly the position shown below:
[image]

I tried to verify my hypothesis as follows.
Since $P$ is located inside $\angle AOB$,
we set its location to $(x, \sqrt{1 - x^2})$ (where $\sqrt{2}/2 < x < 1$).
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\lvert{PA}\rvert
&= \sqrt{(2 - x)^2 + (1 - x^2)} \\
&= \sqrt{5 - 4x}, \\
\lvert{PB}\rvert
&= \sqrt{(2 - x)^2 + (2 - \sqrt{1 - x^2})^2} \\
&= \sqrt{-4\sqrt{1 - x^2} - 4x + 9}, \\
f
&= 2\sqrt{2} \lvert{PA}\rvert + \lvert{PB}\rvert \\
&= 2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{5 - 4x}
+ \sqrt{-4\sqrt{1 - x^2} - 4x + 9}. \\
\end{align*}

I asked [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/dwqhf64w) again to plot $f(x)$:
[image]
and it seems to confirm my conjecture that
$$\min_{\sqrt{2}/2 < x < 1} f(x) = 5$$

## Question

Is my hypothesis correct?
If so, is there a proof of this hypothesis that can be relatively easily by hand
(preferably avoiding, say, the evaluation of $f'(x)$)?
Geometric proofs will be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
No need to use algera or complicated computational method, which still end up with non-strict solution without using computer programming. Actually, only pure geometry is required to solve this problem.

Connect $OB$ and set point $C$ on $OB$ such that $OC=1/(2\sqrt 2).$ Connect $CP.$ Since $OB=2\sqrt 2, OP=r=1,$ we have $\triangle OPC\sim \triangle OBP$. So, $PC=PB/(2\sqrt 2)$. Therefore, when $A, P $, and $C $ are collinear, we have minimum of $PA+PC=PA+BP/(2\sqrt 2).$ With coordinates of $C$ and $A$ being $(1/4, 1/4)$ and $(2,0)$ respectively, we can quickly find the minimum of $PA+BP/(2\sqrt 2) =AC=5\sqrt2/4.$ Therefore, the minimum of $2\sqrt2 PA+PB=2\sqrt2(5\sqrt2 /4)=5$

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is true.

Indeed the solution of the equation:
$$
2\sqrt{10-8x}+\sqrt{9-4x-4\sqrt{1-x^2}}=5
$$
is
$$
x=\frac{2+7\sqrt{46}}{50},\text{ with } \sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{14-\sqrt{46}}{50}.
$$

Substituting this into the derivative of the distance one obtains:
$$
\left[-\frac{8}{\sqrt{10-8x}}+\frac{2(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{9-4x-4\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right]_{x=\frac{2+7\sqrt{46}}{50}}\\
=-\frac{4(14+\sqrt{46})}{15}+\frac{4(14+\sqrt{46})}{15}=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you!  I am still hoping to find a solution that doesn't require a lot of calculation, but I will accept the derivative argument if more intuitive proofs turn out to be hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is interesting for sure but I believe that the solution is biased by the fact that $x_A=x_B=y_A$.

I tried to make it more general with $A(x_A,y_A)$ and $B(x_B,0)$ assuming that both points are in the first quadrant. Let $(X,\sqrt{1-X^2})$ the coordinates of point $P$ and assume that we want to minimize
$$f = k\lvert{PA}\rvert + \lvert{PB}\rvert$$

We then have
$$\lvert{PA}\rvert=\sqrt{(X-x_A)^2+\left(\sqrt{1-X^2}-y_A\right)^2}$$
$$ \lvert{PB}\rvert=\sqrt{-2 x_B X+x_B^2+1}$$ which make
$$f=k\sqrt{(X-x_A)^2+\left(\sqrt{1-X^2}-y_A\right)^2}+\sqrt{-2 x_B X+x_B^2+1}$$ to be an hightly nonlinear equation in $X$; this means that, for getting its solution, we need some *reasonable estimate*.

To generate it, in a preliminary step, let us consider that we want to minimize
$$g= k^2\lvert{PA}\rvert^2 + \lvert{PB}\rvert^2$$ which is more pleasant. Computing its derivative, we have
$$\frac{dg}{dX}=2 k^2 \left(\frac{X y_A}{\sqrt{1-X^2}}-x_A\right)-2 x_B=0\implies X=\frac{k^2 x_A+x_B}{\sqrt{\left(k^2 x_A+x_B\right)^2+k^4 y_A^2}}$$

For the example given in the post, this would give as an estimate $X=\frac{9}{\sqrt{82}}\approx 0.993884$ while the exact solution of the problem is $X=\frac{2+7 \sqrt{46}}{50}\approx 0.989526$.

Back to $f$, computing its derivative, we need to solve for $X$
$$\frac{k X y_A-k \sqrt{1-X^2} x_A}{\sqrt{1-X^2} \sqrt{-2 X x_A+x_A^2-2
   \sqrt{1-X^2} y_A+y_A^2+1}}-\frac{x_B}{\sqrt{-2 X x_B+x_B^2+1}}=0$$ which will require a numerical method such as Newton (this will be simple because we already have a good estimate.

For illustration, let us use $x_A=3$, $y_A=4$ and $x_B=5$ and $k=2\sqrt 2$. The preliminary process gives $X_0=\frac{29}{\sqrt{1865}}\approx 0.671519$.

Newton iterates will then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & X_n & f(X_n) \\
 0 & 0.67151942 & 15.72034369 \\
 1 & 0.77667655 & 15.68958161 \\
 2 & 0.75966295 & 15.68798018 \\
 3 & 0.75880236 & 15.68797655 \\
 4 & 0.75880040 & 15.68797655
\end{array}
\right)$$